# Cookie deleted after site refresh

Tags: reactjs, docker, go, cookies, backend

I have a React frontend with a Golang backend. Both are hostes on my vps. While the backend is deployed to a docker container that runs on the port 8081 of my vps, the frontend is linked to its domain through a virtualHost. In my backend there is an endpoint that handles logins. It sets a cookie with the users JWT-token. It works, but on refresh of the page the token is gone, no cookies are set anymore.

The backend endpoints handler:

```
func (app *application) Login(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    if r.Method != "POST" {
        w.Header().Set("Allow", "POST")
        http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusMethodNotAllowed), http.StatusMethodNotAllowed)
        return
    }

    var User UserLoginBody
    decoder := json.NewDecoder(r.Body)
    if err := decoder.Decode(&User); err != nil {
        app.server_error(w, err)
        return
    }

    userID, err := app.users.Authenticate(User.Email, User.Password)
    if err != nil {
        app.server_error(w, err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("User ID:", userID)
    tokenString, err := app.user_helpers.GenerateToken(userID)
    if err != nil {
        println(userID, tokenString)
        app.server_error(w, err)
        return
    }

    http.SetCookie(w, &http.Cookie{
        Name:     "token",
        Value:    tokenString,
        MaxAge:   3600,
        HttpOnly: false,
        Secure:   true,
        SameSite: http.SameSiteNoneMode,
    })

    w.WriteHeader(http.StatusOK)
}
```

and here on the frontend I make the call:

```
const LoginForm = () => {
  const form = useForm<SignInSchemaType>({
    resolver: zodResolver(SignInSchema),
    defaultValues: {
      userEmail: "",
      userPassword: "",
    }
  })
  const navigate = useNavigate();
  const { toast } = useToast()
  const [isPassword, setIsPassword] = useState(true);

  const handleLogin = async (values: SignInSchemaType) => {
    try {
      const response = await fetch("https://cihanbatasul.com:8081/login", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify(values),
        credentials: "include",
      });
      if (!response.ok) {
        toast({
          variant: "destructive",
          title: "Failure",
          description: "There was a problem with the login. PLease make sure you have the right credentials."
        })
      }
      if (response.ok) {
        toast({
          variant: "default",
          title: "Success",
          description: "Welcome back!"
        })
        navigate(-1);
      }
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error)
      toast({
        variant: "destructive",
        title: "Failure",
        description: "There was a problem with the login. PLease make sure you have the right credentials."
      })
    }
  }

  return (
    <motion.div
      key={"login-form"}
      initial={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0 }}
      animate={{ opacity: 1, scale: 1 }}
      exit={{ opacity: 0, scale: 0 }}
      transition={{ duration: 0.6, ease: easeInOut }}
      className="w-full h-full flex flex-col gap-3 text-inherit  p-3 md:p-6 lg:p-12"
    >
      <Form  {...form}>
        <form onSubmit={form.handleSubmit(handleLogin)} className="space-y-8">
          <FormField control={form.control} name="userEmail" render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem>
              <FormControl>
                <Input LabelText="Email" type="email" {...field} />
              </FormControl>
              <FormMessage />
            </FormItem>
          )}
          />
          <FormField control={form.control} name="userPassword" render={({ field }) => (
            <FormItem>
              <FormControl>
                <PasswordInput
                  {...field}
                  fullWidth={true}
                  PlacerholderText="Password"
                  isPassword={isPassword}
                  onVisible={setIsPassword}
                />
              </FormControl>
              <FormMessage />
            </FormItem>
          )}
          />
          <Button className="w-full bg-blue-600 rounded-lg hover:bg-blue-700 py-2 text-white cursor-pointer" type="submit">Submit</Button>
        </form>
      </Form>
    </motion.div>
  );
};

export default LoginForm;
```

In my frontend I try to get the token here in my navbar:

```
 const getJwtFromCookie = () => {
        const cookieValue = document.cookie
            .split('; ')
            .find(row => row.startsWith('token='))
            ?.split('=')[1];
        return cookieValue;
    };


    const token = getJwtFromCookie()
        if (token) {
            dispatch(setToken(token))
        }
    const isUserLoggedIn = useSelector((state: RootState) => state.user.isLoggedIn)
```

The cookie should be dispatched here and if it exists, the variable isUserLoggedIn should be true.

This is the userSlice:

```
import { createSlice, PayloadAction } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import {ShelvesResponse } from "@/views/UserProfile";
interface User {
    userID?: string | null  
    isLoggedIn: boolean
    token: string | null
    userName: string 
    shelves: ShelvesResponse
    recommendations: string[]
    authors: string[] 
}

const initialState: User = {
    userID: null, 
    isLoggedIn: false,
    token: null,
    userName: "",
    shelves: {
        userName: "User",
        AllShelves: [
          {
            shelfType: "curr",
            shelf: [
              {
                bookID: "1",
                title: "Current Book",
                author: "Author 1",
                description: "Description of the current book",
                picture: "url-to-book-image",
                added_at: Date()
    
              },
            ],
          },
          {
            shelfType: "fav",
            shelf: [
              {
                bookID: "2",
                title: "Favorite Book",
                author: "Author 2",
                description: "Description of the favorite book",
                picture: "url-to-book-image",
                added_at: Date()

              },
            ],
          },
          {
            shelfType: "wtr",
            shelf: [
              {
                bookID: "3",
                title: "Want to Read Book",
                author: "Author 3",
                description: "Description of the want to read book",
                picture: "url-to-book-image",
                added_at: Date()

              },
            ],
          },
          {
            shelfType: "read",
            shelf: [
              {
                bookID: "4",
                title: "Read Book",
                author: "Author 4",
                description: "Description of the read book",
                picture: "url-to-book-image",
                added_at: Date()

              },
            ],
          },
        ],
      },    
      recommendations: [],
      authors: []  
}

const userSlice = createSlice({
    name: "user", 
    initialState,
    reducers: {
      setAuthors: (state, action: PayloadAction<string[]>) => {
      state.authors = action.payload
    },
      setRecommendations: (state, action:PayloadAction<string[]>) => {
        state.recommendations = action.payload
      },
        setShelves: (state, action: PayloadAction<ShelvesResponse>) => {
            state.shelves = action.payload
        },
        setToken: (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) =>{
            state.token = action.payload
            state.isLoggedIn = !!action.payload
            console.log(state.token)
        },
        logoutUser: (state) => {
            document.cookie = "token=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:00 UTC; path=/;"        
            state.token = null
            state.isLoggedIn = false 
        },
        setID: (state, action: PayloadAction<string>) => {
            state.userID = action.payload
        }
    }
})

export const {setToken, logoutUser, setID, setShelves, setRecommendations, setAuthors} = userSlice.actions

export default userSlice.reducer
```

Here are screenshots of the browser after I log in:
[image]
[image]

In the end the problem is that the user doesn't get logged in. When I log in the "success" popop appears, telling the user that he logged in successfully, but then nothing happens (the users profile should be visitable etc.)
Does anyone know what the issue could be?
Thank you!